# Rxjs combinelatest observable value is undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code where Obs2 depends on Obs1.  However, when I use combineLatest, I keep getting undefined for the value of Obs1. How can I get this to work?  I basically just need Obs2$ to filter out the value that exist in Obs1$.

```
  this.Obs2$ = this.dataService.getObs2(this.id); 
  this.Obs1$ = this.dataService.getObs1(this.id)
    .pipe(
      map(item => {
        return item.prop1
      }),
      tap( val => console.log('the tapped value: ', val)) // shows undefined
    );

  this.CombinedObs$ = 
  combineLatest(this.Obs1$,this.Obs2$)
  .pipe(
    map(([Obs1,Obs2]) => {
      return Obs2
        .filter(t => !Obs1.includes(t.prop1)) //obs1 keeps coming in as undefined
        .map(item => {
                return {
                  entityId: item.teamId, 
                  entityName: item.teamName, 
                  entityCategory: ''
                }})
    })
  )
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it with combineLatest. Because combineLAtest starts emitting value whenever one of the observables start emitting. If you want do it sequentially you shouldn't use combineLatest. Also can you please specify " I basically just need Obs2$ to filter out the value that exist in Obs1$", what does that mean?

Comment: If not combineLatest then what can I use?  I need Obs2$ to not contain any itemids that exist in Obs1$.

Comment: You can use forkJoin instead. forkJoin waits until all the observables complete.

Comment: I had already tried forkJoin and was getting the same problem.  I know that Obs1 is getting data.  The problem may just be that Obs2 is somehow being called first.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting valid data from `Obs1$`? Can you please check once by adding a `tap` operator before `map`.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that Ajay had spotted the error in his answer below.  I was not mapping the list correctly as he points out.  Applying his fix resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue what you are doing wrong is on map pipe, let me know if that return you results:

```
this.Obs2$ = this.dataService.getObs2(this.id); 
  this.Obs1$ = this.dataService.getObs1(this.id)
    .pipe(
      map(items => items.map(item => item.prop1)), // Issue was here
      tap( val => console.log('the tapped value: ', val)) // It will not show undefinded now
    );

  this.CombinedObs$ = 
  combineLatest(this.Obs1$,this.Obs2$)
  .pipe(
    map(([Obs1,Obs2]) => {
      return Obs2
        .filter(t => !Obs1.includes(t.prop1)) //obs1 keeps coming in as undefined
        .map(item => {
                return {
                  entityId: item.teamId, 
                  entityName: item.teamName, 
                  entityCategory: ''
                }}) // I'm sure you will get error over here so please review and handle that accordingly 
    })
  )
```

Comment: Obs1 is what is showing as undefined.  I am not getting an error in the mapping.

Comment: I had missed your initial comment.  That resolved the undefined issue.  However, I'm getting 8 calls now, 4 for Obs1 and 4 for Obs2.  Do I need to do a take(1) or something to prevent the duplicate calls?

Comment: I see what my problem is.  I'm using a nested component and so the calls are made for every child that is added to the parent page.  I just need to move my logic to the parent somehow.

Comment: @mo_maat great you found the issue, let me know if you need me. Thanks!